# Ash falling from the sky

Tags: internal-consistency

If ash started to fall from the sky constantly at the rate of very light snow, how would we be affected and what would we need to do to minimise the effects?

I understand the ash would mount up slowly and require constant removal, and I assume a lot of machinery would be damaged.

Comment: "How would we be affected" is a very broad question. Would you mind limiting the scope to a specific field of interest?

Answer (score 1):

There would be many varying effects on many varying scales:

- At the largest scales, if ash was falling from the sky everywhere, it would change the albedo (reflectivity) of the Earth.  If this was very white ash, we could have effects similar to a nuclear winter.  If it was very black ash, more like soot, it might have the opposite warming effect.
- Plant life will be massively affected.  Ash may build up on leaves, impeding photosynthesis (if there is any light that gets through the falling ash).  Ash may affect soil pH, killing many plants.  It would build up like a layer of mulch, preventing seeds from reaching soil.  I would expect the lifecycle of many plants to simply cease.
- Maintaining any mechanical device with an air filter or radiator  would be treacherous due to clogging.  Few such systems are built for such extremes.  You may still have power, though.  Power plants *may* be less affected by air quality, especially coal ones.
- Its unclear how it would affect the human body without known more of what kind of ash it is.  If it is coal ash, that would cause serious health issues in every human being due to toxic elements found in coal ash.

The best way to mitigate these issues?  Move.  What you describe is actually one step worse than nuclear winter, so the best way to survive is to not be there.